# Pass a child component as Parameter in Blazor

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I would like to do in Blazor something that I normally do in React: create a reusable component that internally uses other child components, with the ability to pass those child components as parameters. I need that to be able to treat child components as a dependency that can be injected on demand with any custom implementation that could be needed in different contexts.

Imagine, for instance, a `TextBox.razor` component that gives you the ability to pass a custom component to render the label as you want, as long as it implements an `ILabel` interface. I tried something like this but the syntax doesn't seem to be valid:

#### TextBox.razor

[image]

As you see from the screenshot, Blazor doesn't allow me to use the Parameter `Label` as a component. Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a component instance, or a Type?

Comment: @PeterMorris an instance

Comment: Will render fragments do what you want?

Comment: Not really... what I had in mind was a sort of "dependency injection" of components. I code using interfaces, and then I can decide to swap the implementation.

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you want. You cannot move an existing instance to another part of the DOM.

Comment: I have opened an issue in github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17502

Comment: Surely you could register an abstract factory?

Comment: Yeah... As I eventually mentioned in the github issue, that is possible. It's just that the amount of code required for that makes the entire operation ridiculous. I suggested a solution, but the team rejected it.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to accomplish this with templated components.

Textbox.razor

```
@typeparam inputType
<div class="textbox">
    @if(LabelTemplate!=null && TItem!=null)
        @LabelTemplate(TItem)
    <input type="text"/>
</div>


    @code{
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<inputType> LabelTemplate { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public inputType TItem { get; set; }
    }
```

In the code above, you are specifying that the component accepts a type using `@typeparam inputType` and receive an object of that type as a parameter `TItem`.

You are also accepting a `LabelTemplate` which accepts an object of type `inputType`. To render this fragment, we call `@LabelTemplate` and pass in our `TItem` parameter.

Now lets look at how to use our templated component in a new component called PersonForm.razor

PersonForm.razor

```
<Textbox TItem="myPerson">
    <LabelTemplate>
        @context.Name
    </LabelTemplate>
</Textbox>
<Textbox TItem="myPerson">
    <LabelTemplate>
        @context.PhoneNumber
    </LabelTemplate>
</Textbox>

@code{

  Person myPerson = new Person { Name = "Jane Doe", PhoneNumber = "999 999 9999" };
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm passing in my Person object to each Textbox component's TItem property, and accessing it in the LabelTemplate using the `@context` syntax.

This might seem confusing at first, so please read up on it [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-templated-components-in-blazor/)

**Edited**
It just depends on what you want to accomplish. With the Verbose syntax comes flexibility on the "implementation" side of the component. Instead of forcing an interface that might not work with a wide variety of models/classes, you are letting the implementation specify what to do.

If you want something less verbose/more rigid, you can do the following as well.

```
@implements ILabel 
<div class="textbox"> 
    <label>@Text</label> 
    <input type="text"/> 
</div> 
@code
{ 
    [Parameter] 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

ILabel.cs

```
    public interface ILabel
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is a way to achieve a similar result, but it's not quite what I was looking for. This feels incredibly verbose compared to just passing the component type as a parameter.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your original intent. See edited part of my answer

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is probably late, but I just struggled through this and found out it is SUPER easy!  Thought I would put an easy answer out there for people looking.

Here is my ***OrdersNavigation.razor*** file (which I want to embed into a header):

```
<div class="nav-strip">
    <NavLink href="orders">
        <Icon Name="@Icons.Cart" /> List
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink href="orders/create">
        <Icon Name="@Icons.Plus" /> Create
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

Now here is my ***PageHeader.razor***:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>@Title</h3>
    @Navigation
</h3>
<hr />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = "[TITLE]";
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Navigation { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the *Navigation* property is a **RenderFragment** - this is key.  Now in my page, I can simply add it like this:

```
<PageHeader Title="Orders">
    <Navigation>
        <OrderNavigation />
    </Navigation>
</PageHeader>
```

You see here that the *Title* parameter is entered like usual, but the *Navigation* parameter is entered as an element of *PageHeader*! Really, you can put anything in the  tags and it will render where you have *@Navigation*.

**Reference: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-data-to-a-renderfragement/**

Took a shot at your example:

**Label.razor**

```
<label>@Text</label>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Text { get; set; }
}
```

**TextBox.razor**

```
<div class="textbox">
    <Label>
        <Text>
            <div>
                Embedded label <br />
                You can even drop components in here!
            </div>
        </Text>
    </Label>
    <input  />
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, you are just rendering whatever component is passed as RenderFragment. In my example, I defined a precise interface `ILabel` which serves as a constraint of what implementation can be used.